# How to retrieve an element inside a Map<> in Java?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, hashmap

I have this Map (don't mind the names because are generic):

`Map<Enum, List<anObject>> map;`

It gives me back a nested Json like this:

```
"map": {
        "ENUM1": [{
          "string1" : "Something written here",
          "check" : true,
          "string2" : "Something written here",
        }],
        "ENUM2": [{
          "string1" : "Something written here",
          "check" : true,
          "string2" : "Something written here",

        }]
     }
```

How do I get "string1" from the first Enum object ENUM1 to save it into a variable?

Maybe this is a stupid question but I didn't find nothing like this on the site.
Thank you!

Comment: `"string1"` seems to be *a key* inside *anObject* inside the list. It is not possible to get just `"string1"` because there is no way to differentiate it from `"string2"`, which is just another key in the same object, keys have no order. Your example is too broad to help you.

Comment: `String value = map.get(Enum.ENUM1).get(0).getString1()`

Comment: A Map in Java does not return JSON but Java objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ENUM values on the map seem like another map. Therefore I put it like this

```
Map<Enum, Map<String, Object>>
```

However, question is not clear! Here is one possible solution.

```
import java.util.*;    
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Enum, Map<String, Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Object> value = new HashMap<>();
        value.put("String1", "Something written here");
        value.put("check", true);
        value.put("String2", "Something written here");
        map.put(Enum.ENUM1, value);
        value = new HashMap<>();
        value.put("String1", "Something written here");
        value.put("check", true);
        value.put("String2", "Something written here");
        map.put(Enum.ENUM2, value);

        //string1 Object always will be String
        String result;
        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry :  map.get(Enum.ENUM1).entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().equals("string1")) {
                result = entry.getValue().toString();
            }
        }

    }
}

enum Enum {
    ENUM1,
    ENUM2
}
```